# No label/attribute for some Kafka consumer metrics exposed by Spring boot actuator and micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I've configured Spring boot actuator and micrometer for exposing Kafka consumer metrics. Some of the Kafka metrics don't have 'topic' label. For example,

```
kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total{client_id="consumer-1",topic="topic1",} 0.0
kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total{client_id="consumer-2",topic="topic2",} 0.0
kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total{client_id="consumer-3",topic="topic3",} 0.0

kafka_consumer_commit_latency_max_seconds{client_id="consumer-1",} 0.013
kafka_consumer_commit_latency_max_seconds{client_id="consumer-2",} 0.013
kafka_consumer_commit_latency_max_seconds{client_id="consumer-3",} 0.013
```

My question is

1. Is there any configuration required to show 'topic' label for metric  kafka_consumer_commit_latency_max_seconds?
2. I noticed that client_id="consumer-1" is same for topic="topic1" even after application restart. Can I rely on client_id to be always point to the specific topic?

Answer (score 0):

Some metrics are global for the Consumer; some are specific to a topic and some are specific to a topic/partition.

The client.id is fixed; when generated by the kafka-clients, there is no guarantee you will always get the same one for a topic, but you can set a specific `ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID` for each consumer.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I was able to set ClientIdPrefix for each consumer.

Comment: Gary Russell - Does Spring boot also exposes Kafka Producer metrics? I am seeing only consumer metrics.

Comment: Not before version 2.3, see `KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration`; 2.3 now exposes both - it no longer uses the deprecated JMX-scraped metrics it uses the newer `KafkaClientMetrics` from Micrometer.